# SQL help - only get distinct records using expect clause and then add a loaddatetime column

Tags: sql, oracle, databricks

I am trying to retrieve only distinct records from table by excluding the system columns (`LoadDate, LoadDateTime, SourceFilename`) because of duplicate records being loaded and system load dates are different.

So by using the below query i get for example only 1 record but if i dont use expect will get 10 records because of dupes.

```
select distinct * except (LoadDate, LoadDateTime, SourceFilename)
from a;
```

Now once i get the distinct record, i would like to append/add the LoadDateTime column data with the distinct query result so i also can use the LoadDateTime column data later to validate.

But i am struggling to find a way

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks much

I tried various ways like inner query, partitioned by and other but no solution still

Answer (score 0):

> Now once I get the distinct record, I would like to append/add the `LoadDateTime` column data with the distinct query result so I also can use the `LoadDateTime` column data later to validate.

You say "once I get the distinct record" but which row is the distinct record as you have combined 10 rows to get that single row of output? Let us assume that you want the row which has the latest `LoadDateTime` then you can do that using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

I don't use Databricks and the documentation does not give a complete syntax diagram for the [`PARTITION BY` clause of a window function](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-window-functions.html#syntax) so this may not work but you can try:

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT (rn)
FROM   (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(LoadDate, SourceFilename),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY * EXCEPT (LoadDate, LoadDateTime, SourceFilename)
           ORDER BY LoadDateTime DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   a
) a_with_rn
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

If you cannot use `PARTITION BY * EXCEPT (...)` then you will have to name all the columns (which is considered better practice) and can use:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col4,
       LoadDateTime
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         col3,
         col4,
         LoadDateTime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4
           ORDER BY LoadDateTime DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   a
) a_with_rn
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

You could also try aggregating:

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(LoadDate, LoadDateTime, SourceFilename),
       MAX(LoadDateTime) AS LoadDateTime
FROM   a
GROUP BY
       * EXCEPT(LoadDate, LoadDateTime, SourceFilename)
```

*(Again, the [syntax diagrams in the documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html) are not clear whether using `* EXCEPT (...)` in a `GROUP BY` clause is acceptable - you would have to try it and see. If it does not work then you would have to name all the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause and, maybe, the `SELECT` clause)*

Comment: I have tried option 1 (PARTITION BY * EXCEPT) and option 3 (GROUP BY
  * EXCEPT) but it wont work in databricks as it throws this error - Invalid usage of '*' in expression `windowspecdefinition`. Option 2 of adding all the columns is good only if the table columns are less, in my case there are more than 100 cols.

Comment: @user23705977 The simplest solution is to stop using `* EXCEPT (...)` and name all the columns (and it is also considered better practice) - which would be option 2.

Comment: i get you but the table has more than 100 columns and i need to replicate the same logic on 20 other tables which is not feasible

Comment: @user23705977 It is feasible - generate a list of all the columns in the table and then you can copy-paste it into the query wherever you need it. You can argue that it makes the query longer, less-maintainable, harder-to-read, etc. but those metrics just might make it less practical rather than "unfeasible". However, your problem is coming up with a method that gets the same result and allows you to use `* EXCEPT (...)`; someone might suggest something but I can't think of anything that I haven't already suggested.